# how to make multimedia keys work on dell studio 1555

Tags: multimedia

all my function keys work fine except the play/pause,previous and next keys.I have been looking for a solution but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try the troubleshooting steps provided on the Ubuntu Wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting